# Changing Stanford Dependency Parser POS tags Label

Tags: c#, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford.NLP.NET installed as IKVM nugget in my current C# project. From which I'm extracting PoS tags from dependency tree. But for some reasons I want to aggregate various types of noun, adjective, verb and adverb tags labels.

For example,

**"n" label for all noun types**

NN  Noun, singular or mass

NNS     Noun, plural

NNP     Proper noun, singular

NNPS    Proper noun, plural

**"a" label for all adjective types**

JJ  Adjective

JJR     Adjective, comparative

JJS     Adjective, superlative

**"r" label for all adverb types**

RB  Adverb

RBR     Adverb, comparative

RBS     Adverb, superlative

**"v" label for all verb types**

VBD     Verb, past tense

VBG     Verb, gerund or present participle

VBN     Verb, past participle

VBP     Verb, non-3rd person singular present

VBZ     Verb, 3rd person singular present

Where and what change should I make?

Comment: Why don't you change the labels in the output of the code? For example whenever you see NN or NNS just replace it with N.

Comment: I have about 250 files with each file having about 90 k words that need to be processed each time for different inputs. I don't want to add extra processing on them...

Comment: You are just combining the output labels. Compared to the prediction time, it is much faster.

Comment: actually I was thinking of modifying stanford dependency code, but that was too time consuming to program, So I wrote a substring that gets one alphabet after "\" that serves the purpose...